# jQuery slider with delayed elements/content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery slider similar to this http://www.apple.com/uk/imac/ or http://www.reachlocal.com/.

I believe Apple calls theirs "hero slider".

I was looking at easy slider which is very similar but I want the text to slide in a couple of seconds before or after the image? Mostly visible on the Apple website.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

may be gallery view by Jack Anderson solve your problem
but you should rewrite some j query to reach your result you want
you can split your element in two or three and slide them with delay in your gallery